# Nullpointer exception using networking with JavaFx GUI

Tags: java, networking, nullpointerexception, chat, javafx

sorry about the title I had trouble finding out what I should call it.

So here is the deal! I am currently creating a chat application where I use a Gui using I've created in JavaFx (a Gui that has some graphics on it but I think that is kinda irrelevant) what I have done so far is that I've setup a small server that each client connect to through the program! The main idea is that the clients sends a message to the server and the server will then send it to the other client (which is the whole idea in a chat program) one important note is that I am not using Threads and do not wish to yet!

So to get down to the real problem:

I've created a client class that contains methods to connect, receive and send. my Connect class works fine with my Gui and I am able to connect to the server without any problems!

The problem begins when I try to send to or receive from my server. No matter how many exceptions I throw or how many try Catch I do I get a nullpointer error! I've looked at the code for about 2 hours trying to figure out the problem but without luck! my code are as following:

Client class:

```
private PrintWriter pw;
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public void connect() throws IOException{
    final int portNumber = 6040;

    // du kan vælge at bruge inetadressen til at connecte i socketet.
    InetAddress adr = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", portNumber);
    pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    // outPut - Programmet sender til serveren

    pw.println("Connected waiting for input");
    pw.flush();
    //input - Serveren sender til programmet;
}
public void Send(String x) throws IOException{
    if (x != null) {
        pw.print(x);
        pw.flush(); 
    }else {
    System.out.println("ingen meddelse");
    }

}
public String getInformation(){

    Scanner informationFromServer = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = informationFromServer.nextLine();
    if (x== null) {
        return "";
    }
    return x;
}
```

my simpleController code (the code that controls my GUI):

```
public class SimpleController implements Initializable{

public Button btn_Connect;
private Client client;
public Label chatPerson3;
public Label chatPerson1;
public Label lbl_Chatperson1_userName;
public TextField txt_userName;
public TextField textField_chat;
public TextField txt_ChatPerson1;
public Button Send;
public TextField txt_ChatPerson2;
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    btn_Connect.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {   
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            chatPerson1.setVisible(true);
            lbl_Chatperson1_userName.setText(txt_userName.getText());
        }
    });

    Send.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            String x = textField_chat.getText();
            textField_chat.setText("");
            txt_ChatPerson1.setVisible(true);
            txt_ChatPerson1.setText(x);

            System.out.println(x);
            try {
                client.Send(x);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}}
```

and last but not least my main:

```
public class Main extends Application{



public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    Application.launch(Main.class, (java.lang.String[]) null);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    try {
        Client c = new Client();
        c.connect();
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("testingBackground.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Chatten");
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(
                java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }

}

}
```

The exception I get when I try to send is of course in my client.send() method and if I try to receive before I send then it is in the client.getInformation() method.

What have I done wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: No one knows why it gives me the nullpoint execption? :(

Comment: Edited: added nullpoint execption to TAGS

Comment: How do you know that the connections are made correctly?  A failed connection would result in a null value in the socket variable.

Comment: I have a program that test the connection and it tells me that that my client is connected to the server.

Comment: I don't see you setting the value of the 'client' member variable anywhere in the controller. Presumably, that's why you're getting an NPE on client.send() - client is null.

Comment: i dont initilize the variable but i do have: private Client client;

Comment: Okay i have narrowed down the problem into the following:

in the Client class when i try to send a command using the sendCommando() method then it wont send the id because it cannot find a connection (which is why the socket im using is null)! now in order to fix that i have to initilize the variable when i declare it BUT i am unable to declare it in under my class a complete class cannot throw execptions or try catch. So what do i do?

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this issue?